# Mysql multiple select with multiple different where conditions in the same query

Tags: mysql, where-clause, subquery, multiple-select

I have the following table :

```
+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+
| Product            | website   | is_master          |
+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+
| product A          |       X   | 1                  |
| product A          |       Y   | 0                  |
| product A          |       Z   | 0                  |
| product A          |       C   | 0                  |
| product B          |       D   | 1                  |
| product C          |       E   | 1                  |
+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+
```

I am trying to make a mysql query to get a table a as the following one :

```
+--------------------+------------------+--------------------+
| Product            | master_website   | additional_sites   |
+--------------------+------------------+--------------------+
| product A          |       X          | y,z,c              |
| product B          |       D          | null               |
| product C          |       E          | null               |
+--------------------+------------------+--------------------+
```

I have tried with a subselect query but I failed in both cases.

```
select 
Product, 
    (select Product 
     FROM `table1` 
     LEFT JOIN 
     table2 on table1.id = table2.fk_table1 
     WHERE is_master = 1) is_master, 

    (select group_concat(Product) 
     FROM `table1` 
     LEFT JOIN 
     table2 on table1.id = table2.fk_table1 
     WHERE is_master = 0) additional 

     FROM `table1` 
     LEFT JOIN 
     table2 on table1.id = table2.fk_table1 

WHERE 1 
group by 
Product
```

The problem is that the subselect returns more than one row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ddd814/2/0)

```
SELECT t1.Product,
          t1.website AS master_website, 
          GROUP_CONCAT(t2.website ORDER BY t2.website) AS additional_sites   
     FROM MyTable t1
LEFT JOIN MyTable t2 
       ON t1.Prduct = t2.Prduct AND 
          t2.is_master = 0
    WHERE t1.is_master = 1
 GROUP BY t1.Product
```

Comment: I have added another row for product a with site K and is master 0 [*fiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e41ef/1) give wrong results for your query it is showing K as master website

Comment: @uesr58967 I updated my answer.  Does that work better for you?

Comment: Yes now it seems ok :)

Comment: With this "self join" technique you open a whole new world to me!! thanks, works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can break your joined query in 2 sub selects 1 for selecting only one record per product where is_master = 1 and i assume there will only 1 row with is_master = 1  for each product,Second sub select will select rows where is_master= 0 and then use left join for your sub-selects

```
SELECT t.*,t1.additional FROM 
(SELECT 
Product,
website AS is_master, 
FROM `table1` 
LEFT JOIN 
table2 ON table1.id = table2.fk_table1 
WHERE is_master = 1 
) t
LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT Product ,GROUP_CONCAT(website) additional
  FROM `table1` 
  LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.fk_table1 
  WHERE is_master = 0 
  GROUP BY Product
) t1 ON(t.Product = t1.Product)
```